# Modifying hover over information in thumbnail view in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, picture-library

I want to change hover over information in thumbnail view in SharePoint 2013 replacing the Name/Title with a different field ( for example "Source ID") from the picture library.
Can any one help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

> This was the quick fix to my issue. The hover over in thumbnail view is using the “Title” field. I created a custom view that listed the Name field (which contains the employee’s name) and the Title field (which is currently blank). Switched to Quick Edit and selected a group of Names and copied them to the Title column. Then went back to my thumbnail view and the hover over now contains the employee names.

Source: http://www.sharepointanswers.co.uk/q/answers-changing-hover-over-information-in-thumbnail-view-in-sharepoint-2013-84157.html

Comment: Basically, what  I want is to by using JavaScript to replace the Thumbnail View caption (which is Name/Title field) with a specific field in the library (in my case it is a Source ID).

Comment: Link in the answer is dead.